# I used `sbt-buildinfo` in my project, but it doesn't generate the BuildInfo.scala file

Tags: plugins, sbt

I followed the readme of this sbt plugin: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-buildinfo, but my project doesn't generate any `BuildInfo.scala`, and no errors occurred.

I created a very simple sbt project to show my code: https://github.com/freewind/sbt-buildinfo-test

You can clone it and have a try. I'm not sure what do I miss.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`BuildInfo.scala` is generated in `target/scala-2.11/src_managed/main/sbt-buildinfo`:

```
package hello

import java.io.File
import java.net.URL

/** This object was generated by sbt-buildinfo. */
case object BuildInfo {
  /** The value is "sbt-buildinfo-test". */
  val name: String = "sbt-buildinfo-test"
  /** The value is "1.0". */
  val version: String = "1.0"
  /** The value is "2.11.6". */
  val scalaVersion: String = "2.11.6"
  override val toString: String = "name: %s, version: %s, scalaVersion: %s" format (name, version, scalaVersion)
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I just created an issue on the project: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-buildinfo/issues/52